# Add consecutive entries in a column

Tags: c++, awk, sed, grep, gawk

I have a file that has the format

```
   0.99987799      17743.000    
   1.9996300       75.000000    
   2.9993899       75.000000    
   3.9991500       102.00000    
   4.9988999       131.00000    
   5.9986601       130.00000    
   6.9984102       152.00000    
   7.9981699       211.00000    
   8.9979200       256.00000    
   9.9976797       259.00000    
   10.997400       341.00000    
   11.997200       373.00000
```

What I would like to do is add the data in the second column, every four lines. So a desired output would be

```
1 17743+75+75+102
2 131+130+52+211
3 256+259+341+373
```

How can this be done in awk?

I know that I can find a specific element in the file using

```
awk 'FNR == 5 {print $2}' file
```

but I don't know how to add 4 elements in a row. If I try for instance

```
awk '$2 {print FNR == 5}' file
```

I get nothing but zeros, so I don't know how to parse the column first and then the line. I also tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=4}
{
 for (NR>=1 || NR<=i)
{
print $2
}
}' filename
```

but I get a syntax error at `NR<=i`. I also don't have any idea how to loop on the entire file. Any help or idea would be more than welcome! Or perhaps would it be better to do it in `C++`? I don't know which is more convenient...

I also tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {{sum += $2} if(FNR%4 == 0) { print sum; sum=0}}' infile.dat
```

but it doesn't seem to work properly...

Comment: Can you show what you have got so far?

Comment: @miltonb : I've been trying to find something a few hours now and I don't know how to proceed. Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: I'd try something like this: on BEGIN create accumulator `sum=0`, for every line add `sum += $2`, and after that if it's every fourth line print the result and reinit accumulator: `if(FNR%4 == 0) { print sum; sum=0}`. At the END you might check if the last four is completed and if not print the remaining partial `sum`.

Comment: @CiaPan : Thank you very much for your comment! It doesn't seem to work properly. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. Please check my edited question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR%4==1{sum=$2; next}{sum+=$2} NR%4==0{print ++j,sum;}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
1 17995
2 624
3 1229
```

For first number of a group it stores value of second column in `$2`, for next 3 rows adds the value of the second column and `sum`. for last row of a group `NR%4==0` prints the result.

If you don't need the row numbers before the sum results just remove `++j,`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works fine! I am a bit confused, though... What does the `NR%4` do? I know that NR is the number of lines but what does the `%` do?

Comment: @Thanos, You're welcome, glad it helped. `%` is the Remainder Operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $2}' file | paste -d+ - - - - | bc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I don't understand your code! Probably the factor of 4 comes from the 4 dashes, but I am not sure...

Comment: @Thanos: `awk` prints the second colum items; `paste` replicates them in groups of four, inserting pluses between them, so it makes addition expressions; and finally `bc` calculates those expressions and outputs their values.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
awk '{sum += $2}
FNR%4==0 {print FNR/4, sum; sum = 0}
END {if(FNR%4){print int(FNR/4)+1, sum}}' awktest.txt
```

with the result of:

```
1 17995
2 624
3 1229
```